# Como guardar dos palabras en un String en Java?

Tags: java, string

Estoy empezando a estudiar programación y no se mucho, por eso espero que me podais responder esta duda que tengo.
Intento que guardar los "apellidos" dados por consola en un String, si introduzco los dos apellidos me da error pero si introduzco una sola palabra no me da problemas. He intentado poner `sc.nextLine()`, pero si hago eso me aparece el mensaje de "Introduzca sus apellidos" y el de "Introduzca su fecha de cumpleaños" al mismo tiempo y si pongo cualquier valor me salta error.
Si me podeis ayudar os lo agradecería por toda la eternidad.
Muchas gracias.

```
public class Personas {
private Scanner sc;
private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private int fecha_cumple;
private int edad;
private String sexo;

public void escanear() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre:");
    nombre = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Introduzca sus apellidos:");
    apellidos = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Introducza su fecha de cumpleaños:");
    fecha_cumple = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca su edad:");
    edad = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca su sexo:");
    sexo = sc.next();
}
```

Comment: Algo por aclarar y lo tomes a bien. Tus variables dentro del método `escanear` deben ser asignadas de la siguiente forma -> `this.nombre = "valor a asignar"` o aun mejor el método `get` de la variable en cuestión.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, pero eso ya lo tenia asignado en el codigo, lo que no lo puse por no extender demasiado la pregunta ya que imagino que es irrelevante para mi duda. Aun así muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la razón por la que se salta es porque el `next()` no reconoce el enter cuando lo presionas, por lo que se crea una nueva linea y se salta la de "Introduzca sus apellidos", si quieres mas información, puedes consultar [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) que lo explican un poco mejor
Este método también tiene un limitador que es el espacio, asi que cuando vas a guardar 2 palabras, solo leerá la primera

Pon a leer los string con `nextLine()` para que reconozca el espacio y el enter, algo asi

```
       sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre:");
    nombre = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Introduzca sus apellidos:");
    apellidos = sc.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Introducza su fecha de cumpleaños:");
    fecha_cumple = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Introduzca su edad:");
    edad = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca su sexo:");
    sexo = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println(nombre+" "+apellidos+" "+fecha_cumple+" "+edad+" "+sexo);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto excepto el ultimo `sc.nextLine()` que me salta al siguiente objeto que tengo creado de la clase. Pero solucionado poniendo `sc.next()` en ese ultimo elemento. Una vez más muchisimas gracias y me leeré la pregunta que me has indicado.